# Relating blobs from frame i to frame i+1?

Tags: visual-c++, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

I have this tricky task of relating blobs in frame i to those in frame i+1. I haven't found enough articles/examples that deal with this, or those that I could understand well. All I want to do is relate the blobs in frame i to the blobs in frame i+1. The goal is not to detect the same blob again in the next frame (or ignore old ones).

An article/example is welcome. Thx

Comment: I already have blobs detected in the frame sequence using background subtraction and findcontours function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a "multiple objects tracking" problem. If your blobs are identical to each other, this could be hard, otherwise you can first define a distance between two blobs (it depends on how you represent the blob mathematically), given a blob X in frame i, to find it in the frame i+1 is just like looking for the most similar blob to X in frame i+1.

Ideally, a blob will not move too much between two frames. So, to save your life, you can just  put the X into frame i+1 at the same location of it in frame i and looking for the most similar one around it in frame i+1.

Hope these help.

Comment: **Additional info; the blob size is not constant since they are moving closer to the camera.** But I think the location could be helpful. I have caculated moments for the blobs so far. So probably i'll have to get its location in frame i and compare with that in frame i+1.

Answer (score 2):

If the blobs change their size from frame to frame, you must use a scale-invariant descriptor of the blob in order to compare two blobs. cv::HuMomments are such descriptors. You can also use the function cv::matchShapes to directly compare contours which you have detected in subsequent images.

If the movement of the blobs from frame to frame is very small, then you can save the center position of the blobs in the first frame and identify the corresponding blobs in the second frame by taking those blobs which are closest those centers. (as mr.pppoe has mentioned before)

Another possibility is to sample points within (if they have some texture) and on the border of the contour of each blob and use Lucas Kanade Tracking (cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK). The median optical flow could tell you where your blobs moved.

You could also run Lucas Kanade Tracking for each blob individually. Set the `prevPts` to the center of the blob and the `winSize` should exactly match the size of your blob.

The Lucas Kanade Tracking algorithm in OpenCV can only track small translational displacements. If you also have large rotations, you would need a template tracking algorithm which optimizes over the rotation aswell. Here you find a nice [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24809/Image-Alignment-Algorithms) about this and [here](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~cmei/SingleViewpointTracking.html)'s more advanced research about this.

In order to give you more ideas, we would need more information on how the blobs look like, how they move, how large they are etc. Post some pictures!